# Add skype people to group vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, skype4com

How can I add skype people to a group using vb.Net? I use this:

```
 msgl.Chat.SendMessage("/add " & t)
```

which works, but when I do it in a For statement, to add multiple people, it only adds one, example:

```
 For r = 0 To s
 msgl.Chat.SendMessage("/add " & t & r)
 Next
```

Any help? I think I just search for an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

In the second example with the For loop, you are adding t every time. Maybe use `msgl.Chat.SendMessage("/add " & r)`.

Comment: no, t is the prefix, so if t  = test it should add first t0 then t1 then t2... but it doesn't do that